# How do I add specific images in HTML with specific height and width?

Tags: html

Write the HTML code for the webpage titled "Internet", that has two paragraphs and an image the width of which is 230 pixels and height of 180 pixels.

Comment: Hmm. use Freelancer.com

Answer (score 1):

Try with HTML tag `height` and `width`

```
<img src="imagefile.jpg" alt="Image" height="180" width="230">
```

You can also use the style tag. For example, you'd have the following code in your text:

```
<img src="imgfile.jpg" alt="Image" style="width:180px;height:230px;">
```

The style tag ensures the image stays that size and overrides any further image size commands

More details  :- https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Image-Width-and-Height-Using-HTML